# Visual Studio Scripts folder not in Features

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have SharePoint hosted app in Visual Studio 2015 Professional and recently completed a git merge from other developer.

After merge Scripts are no longer available online and the scripts folder is not showing in the Packaging explorer. It is also now showing as a regular folder.

[image]
[image]
I am drilling through files from a working solution to my current but cannot locate how or where this is referenced. Sorry still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `SharePointProjectItem.spdata` file under Script folder has been removed. That's why it is looking like this. So recover this file from your commit history. If you can not recover it, then you have create it manually. If you need help to create `SharePointProjectItem.spdata` file, then let me know in comment, I will help you.